# php using PDO to retrieve results

Tags: php, pdo

I've never used PDO before today but I believe from my research that it is most secure for query based transactions. I have the following code executed:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');


$db_conn = new  PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pal','root','root');
$db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$message = "";
$email = "someemail@gmail.com";//($_POST['email']); 


$qry = $db_conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
$qry->bindParam(':email', $email);
$qry->execute();
$result = $qry->fetch();

print_r($result);

echo utf8_encode($message);
?>
```

I've changed the value of email to static one instead $_POST for sake of testing. When this is executed, It returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [email] => someemail@gmail.com
    [1] => someemail@gmail.com
    [password] => test
    [2] => test
    [first_name] => Jay
    [3] => Jay
    [last_name] => Merc
    [4] => Merc
    [birth_year] => 1989
    [5] => 1989
    [gender] => Male
    [6] => Male
    [created_at] => 2014-07-05 22:43:19
    [7] => 2014-07-05 22:43:19
)
```

This is what I get from print_r() function. My question is why am I getting everything duplicated? e.g. [id] showing 0 and next [0] showing [0], and so on. Second question is how can I access email only (I want result of this query to be string of email address only to check if user exists or not for registration purposes)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Side note: I see `utf8_encode()` out there. As of 2014, I think it isn't worth any more to use ISO-8859-1 in your scripts, esp. if you need to generate UTF-8 output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because:

```
$result = $qry->fetch();
```

fetches array with integer index and also by column name.

Use this to fetch array indexed by column name only:

```
$result = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

For further reference on indexes look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

**Second** part, alter your query to this:

```
$qry = $db_conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email');
```

Comment: I used fetchColumn and modified the query to return only email. That worked.